# Pattern matching: Reading innerhtml & writing to text file on the fly - VBScript

Tags: regex, vbscript, match

As a follow up to this question: [Pattern matching in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705258/pattern-matching-in-vbs/28705609#28705609)

I'm trying to implement the pattern match into my FIRST step.  My first step was to dump all of the innerhtml from 1,000's of pages into a text file, then find the pattern matches within the text file using the technique from the link above.  That worked fine for a few innerhtml dumps, but when I processed every page I need, my resulting text file is over 1GB!  When I tried to pattern match against it, it just hung (even left it running all night).

My next thought is to pattern match in my first step against the innerhtml directly so I'm only writing the needed URL to the text file.  Here's what I have - not getting an error, yet the text file is not being populated. Where am I going wrong?

I assume the issue is somewhere in here:

```
Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "LicenseDetail[^']+"

dim matches()
dim iii: iii = 0

strHTML = ie.document.body.innerhtml

Dim objMatch
For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strHTML)
    redim preserve matches(iii)
    matches(iii) = objMatch.SubMatches(0)
    iii = (iii + 1)
Next

'read back
for iii = 0 to ubound(matches)

    set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\AgentURLsRaw.txt",8,true) 
    ts.write matches(iii) 
    ts.close 
next
```

Full Code:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For ii=12 To 81

    If ii=81 Then Exit For

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/wl11.asp?Mode=1&SID=&brd=&typ="
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop

    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("Board").Value = "25"
    Set Form = IE.Document.Forms("reportForm")
    Form.hDDChange.Value = "Y"
    Form.Submit

    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop
    Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("LicenseType").Value = "2501"

    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("County").Value = ii
    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("RecsPerPage").Value = "50"

    For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If btn.type = "image" Then btn.Click()
        Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop
    Next

    Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 15: Loop
    pg = IE.Document.getElementsByName("hTotalPages")(0).Value

    Dim i
    i = 0

    Do while i < pg +1
        i = i + 1

        on error resume next

        Dim objRegExp
        Set objRegExp = New RegExp

        objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegExp.Global = True
        objRegExp.Pattern = "LicenseDetail[^']+"

        dim matches()
        dim iii: iii = 0

        strHTML = ie.document.body.innerhtml

        Dim objMatch
        For Each objMatch in objRegExp.Execute(strHTML)
            redim preserve matches(iii)
            matches(iii) = objMatch.SubMatches(0)
            iii = (iii + 1)
        Next

        'read back
        for iii = 0 to ubound(matches)

            set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
            set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\AgentURLsRaw.txt",8,true) 
            ts.write matches(iii) 
            ts.close 
        next

        Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 15: Loop
        For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
            If btn.name = "SearchForward" and btn.value = "Search" Then btn.Click()
        Next
    loop

next
Wscript.echo DONE
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have found that reading and manipulating binary and text files bigger than about 250MB in VBScript pretty much impossible. Have you considered just logging to multiple files then looping through them 1 at a time?

Comment: Worst case scenario, I can manually set a number of pages to scrape, but I'm thinking extracting ONLY what I need from the innerhtml (as opposed to the entire body) would produce much smaller files.  I think I'm close in my approach above, but it's not quite working.  Not sure why it wouldn't be finding matches.  It's the same data, only I'm trying to read the innerhtml on the fly as opposed to what's stored in a text file.  I'm making a big assumption that this case be done...

Comment: Is it apparent to anyone where I went wrong implementing the pattern search against innerhtml?

Comment: Since we don't have sample data to run your code against, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Nathan - not sure I understand.  The full code above will run - it will fill out the form, submit it, scroll through the pages, and even create the .txt file, it just won't write to it - it's either not finding matches (which would be weird because I've used this exact pattern against the same html in a text file), or I'm using regexp wrong here.  Let me know what more I can provide to help you help me.  :)

Comment: Removed "on error resume next".  My code is giving an "invalid procedure call or argument" on line 56 char 4.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Here's my final code in case it's helpful to anyone else:

```
Set objWshShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For ii=12 To 81

If ii=81 Then Exit For

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/wl11.asp?Mode=1&SID=&brd=&typ="
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop

IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("Board").Value = "25"
Set Form = IE.Document.Forms("reportForm")
Form.hDDChange.Value = "Y"
Form.Submit

Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop
Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 10: Loop
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("LicenseType").Value = "2501"

IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("County").Value = ii
IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")("RecsPerPage").Value = "50"

For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If btn.type = "image" Then btn.Click()
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: WScript.sleep 15: Loop
Next

Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 15: Loop
pg = IE.Document.getElementsByName("hTotalPages")(0).Value

Dim i
i = 0

Do while i < pg +1
i = i + 1

on error resume next

strPattern = "LicenseDetail[^""]+"

strTestString = ie.document.body.innerhtml

arrAllMatches = fGetMatches(strPattern, strTestString)

If UBound(arrAllMatches) <> 0 Then 

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\AgentURLsRaw.txt",8,true) 
ts.write Join(arrAllMatches, vbCrlf)
ts.close 

'Reopens newly created txt file and corrects ampersand in addresses
 set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\AgentURLsRaw.txt",1,true)
 tsread2 = ts.ReadAll
 ts.close

 tsreadreplaceAMP = Replace(tsread2, "LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&amp;id=","https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=")

 set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\AgentURLsRaw.txt",2,true)
 ts.WriteLine tsreadreplaceAMP
 ts.Close


Else

WScript.Echo "-- None Found --"

End if

Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete": WScript.sleep 15: Loop
For Each btn In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
If btn.name = "SearchForward" and btn.value = "Search" Then btn.Click()
Next
loop

next
Wscript.echo DONE

Function fGetMatches(sPattern, sStr)
Dim regEx, retVal, sMatch, colMatches, temp
Set regEx = New RegExp     ' Create a regular expression.
regEx.Pattern = sPattern   ' Set pattern.
regEx.IgnoreCase = True   ' Set case insensitivity.
regEx.Global = True        ' Set global applicability.

Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(sStr)   ' Execute search.

If colMatches.Count = 0 Then
    temp = Array("")
Else
    '# Convert Collection to Array
    For Each sMatch In colMatches
        temp = temp & sMatch & "¶"
    Next
    temp = Left(temp, Len(temp) - 1)
    temp = Split(temp, "¶")
End If

fGetMatches = temp
End Function
```

Comment: Can you add notes as to what you changed to fix it? Also, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: I just re-examined my approach from the linked post.  I initially abandoned it after not having any success.  Tough to point to exactly what fixed it, but whatever arrangement I had wasn't working.  I'm reasonably certain I wasn't using the innerhtml and Function() references correctly.  Found the winning combination.